# using if statement in stored procedure in sql

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I  have a stored procedure that is returning me some records. Now I want to change the condition on which the records are being shown on the basis of a condition

```
select * from table
WHERE cond1 = c1
AND cond2 = c2
```

basically I want a structure like this

```
if(Val1= Val2) then  
select * from table
WHERE cond1 = c1
AND cond2 = c2
AND cond3 = c3
else
select * from table
WHERE cond1 = c1
AND cond2 = c2
```

Since the stored proc is huge and I can't change too much in that so I can only change the where condition using if statement.

Comment: OK. So what is your question?

Comment: Its simple I need to embed a condition in where clause if a particular value satisfy the condition.. kind of dynamically editing the where clause in stored procedure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just include the condition in your where clause:

```
select * from table
WHERE cond1 = c1
AND cond2 = c2
AND (Val1 <> Val2 OR cond3 = c3)
```

If this structure keeps expanding - maybe you're doing some form of search with different possible parameters - it's worth reading Erland Sommarskog's [Dynamic Search conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Comment: +1 - I don't know who Erland is, but he has some pretty useful material.

Comment: @MrMoose - I've never seen Erland on here. He used to be quite active on the usenet groups (e.g. microsoft.public.sqlserver.programming), and his work is still superbly researched.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
IF Val1 = Val2 
BEGIN

END
ELSE
BEGIN

END
```

Comment: will it be working within where clause? I mean I just need to add an extra "AND" condition in the where clause3

Comment: If you are wanting to change just the WHERE clause based on the variable values, then you will need to use Dynamic SQL. I mean you cannot simply code - Select * from Table IF var1=var2 WHERE...